# Using Codemirror in a page with ContentEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I am creating a page which embeds a codemirror instance and has a contenteditable section on the page. My motive is to show the html code of the contentEditable section inside the codemirror editor and the codemirror value gets updated whenever user clicks inside the editable section.
The problem which I am facing is that as soon as the user clicks inside the contentEditable section, the code for updating the editor value is run
`editor.setValue(..content value from editable..)` which makes the contentEditable loose focus which makes it impossible to add data to the contentEditable.

How exactly do I prevent this? So that user can directly add text inside the contentEditable section and the codemirror value keeps getting updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CodeMirror event onChange to get focus back to contentEditable section.
[codemirror manual section events](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html)
This event is fired after any change in codemirror editor.

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                lineNumbers: true, 
                matchBrackets: true,  
                onChange: function(instance, changeObj) {
                    //  loose focus here                 
                }  
        });
```

If I understand You corectly, each time user changes something in contentEditable, entire codeMirror editors content is replaced using editor.setValue function. You can using changeObj properties - from and to, in order to indicate whether entire content was replaced and get focus back only when change come from contentEditable. This could prevent loosing focus in codemirror editor on changes made by user.

Comment: hey thanks... it was an internal problem actually in my code.. the setValue was triggering onChange event for the codemirror so I created a flag to prevent that as onChange event had some extra functionality in my code which could not be replaced